# PYTHON 2.7 command prompt stuck when using pip to install

Tags: python

I am trying to use pip to install the python docx plugin. However, when I use the line "pip install python-docx" on the windows command prompt, it just stays there, not doing anything. It doesn't crash, nor does it throw an error.

I have modified the PATH so it includes pip, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Did you start "Command Prompt" as "Administrator"?

Comment: I hadn't. I have just done so, however, and the problem is still exactly the same.

Comment: Do you use firewall or antivirus? Sometime they can interfere with python.

Comment: AT LAST! Thanks a lot. I had been trying to install that plugin for the last three days.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, what happened is that my antivirus was somehow interfering with the installing process. I turned it off for a few minutes, ran the windows command prompt as administrator, and it worked perfectly.